# Android: Using focus mode FOCUS_MODE_EDOF during image capture

Tags: android, image, android-camera

Has anyone used the focus mode FOCUS_MODE_EDOF, provided in the android CameraParameters?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_EDOF

I need to know if this is the mode to be used for tap to focus on the object selected (as depicted in this Iphone 4 camera specs, http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/camera.html)?

If yes, do i need to implement any touch listeners on the preview screen to determine the part of the preview selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: no, this is not the mode you want to use for touch-to-focus.

EDOF stands for "Extended Depth of Field", and in this case, refers to a camera with a fixed focus which uses optical and computational tricks to create an image where everything beyond a certain distance is in focus.  Using the fact that different wavelengths of light will be affected differently by the lens, the color channels can be sharpened separately and combined.  This allows a larger aperture (and thus better performance in low-light conditions) than a conventional fixed-focus lens, which would have to be focused at the hyperfocal distance to focus the entire scene.

EDOF cameras are common on Nokia phones.  Because they don't have moving parts, they can be made smaller and more robust than autofocus cameras.